# Getchildhtml in child

Tags: layout, blocks

I'm trying to include a custom child 
`catalog/product/view/type/options/sizechart.pthml` into `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`.

So far it doesn't show on front-end.

Here is my catalog.xml

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
     <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable.sizechart" as="sizechart" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/sizechart.phtml"/>
```

And my configurable.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sizechart.pthml'); ?>
```

Any idea why it doesn't show?

BTW if I use this code in configurable.phtml it works but I don't think it's the proper way to do it

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/options/sizechart.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be like this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sizechart'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

As Akilesh explains, you need either to use the alias inside the parent <-> child relationship or the full name, in this case:

```
 <block ... name="product.info.options.configurable.sizechart" as="sizechart" .../>
```

This is the alias: `as="sizechart"`  and this the name: `name="product.info.options.configurable.sizechart"`